# AltGr + E not working, WM_KEYDOWN for E missing

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-11, keyboard-layout

When pressing <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> I get no euro char.

Both keys are working regularly in other combinations as well as on their own.

Using Spy++ (as 32bit and 64bit versions separately) I was able to nail down NVIDIA Shadowplay blocking <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> which I was then able to resolve.
When looking at <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> no hotkey or similar action is indicated.

```
WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:VK_CONTROL
WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:VK_MENU
WM_KEYUP nVirtKey:'E'
```

It's to note that working combinations like <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> or <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> had a `WM_KEYDOWN` followed by a `WM_CHAR` - so it seems the `WM_KEYDOWN` for <kbd>E</kbd> is missing.

I checked this with the virtual keyboard as well:
While the euro sign is displayed while pressing <kbd>AltGr</kbd> it cannot be typed - neither by pressing the key on the physical device nor by selecting it on the virtual one.

Any ideas how I could try to tackle this issue and resolve the problem?

Comment: Which keyboard layout are you using? What happens when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: I'm using the German layout (QWERTZ) and it's working perfectly in Safe mode. What's the best way to find the troublemaker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As booting in Safe Mode fixed the keyboard problem, this indicates
that some third-party application that starts with Windows
is responsible for it.

To locate the problematic application, you may use the free tool
[Autoruns for Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns).

This utility shows all programs configured to run during system bootup or login
in its "Everything" tab.
You may turn off startup items with a click and return
them later with another click. You may avoid listing Microsoft products by
using the menu *Options > Hide Microsoft Entries*,
*Hide Empty Locations* and *Hide Windows Entries*

I would suggest drilling down to find the startup program that causes
this behavior, by turning off startup entries in bunches, and reboot to
test.

Once identified, the product might have some setting
that can avoid the problem, or can be left out of startup and only be invoked
when required (verify that once invoked it does not add another startup
entry).

Comment: Thank you, the problem was the Easy Mouse setting for Mouse Without Borders in PowerToys.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **PowerToys** and have opted to run **Mouse Without Borders**, it maps a Shortcut to toggle Easy Mouse to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> per default, which overrides <kbd>AltGr</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> to €. Just disable this shortcut.